# how to programmatically run the before_destroy and other Active record hooks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, hook

I wan to override the destroy and the destroy_all, and the delete and the delete_all methods in rails to accomplish soft deletion (set active bit to false), without using any plugin for that. I want to run the before_destroy filter in these actions where appropriate. So how can i run the before_destroy hook, and other such hooks, programmatically from rails code? As a side question, what other detail should i be aware of when trying to monkeypatch an activerecord method like destroy, destroy_all etc?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to follow the hard way :) Maybe a gem like https://github.com/JackDanger/permanent_records could help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar SO question, whose answer might be of help:

[My custom destroy method does not trigger the default before and after destroy callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942390/my-custom-destroy-method-does-not-trigger-the-default-before-and-after-destroy-ca#answers-header)

self.class.before_destroy_callback_chain and the self.class.after_destroy_callback_chain can give the list of methods to call. but dont know if this is the complete answer or not.